# Reset Series index without turning into DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, simulation, montecarlo

When I use `Series.reset_index()` my variable turns into a `DataFrame` object. Is there any way to reset the index of a series without incurring this result?

The context is a simulation of random choices based on probability (monte carlo sim), where selections made from series are omitted with `series.pop(item)`.

I require the index reset because I iterate through in order to create a cumulative frequency series.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try `drop=True` in `.reset_index` i.e. `series.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`

According to [document](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

> drop : boolean, default False
>
> Do not try to insert index into dataframe columns.

Example:

```
series = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,1,1])
print(series)
```

Series result:

```
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
5    1
6    1
dtype: int64
```

selecting some values from series:

```
filtered = series[series.values==1]
print(filtered)
```

Result:

```
0    1
5    1
6    1
dtype: int64
```

Reseting index:

```
filtered.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
print(filtered)
```

Result:

```
0    1
1    1
2    1
dtype: int64
```

With `type(filtered)` still returns `Series`.

Comment: however this seems to empty the series, if reassigning a reset-indexed `series` to itself  i.e.  `f = f.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`

Comment: You do not need to reassign it after `inplace`, it does not return anything, it already changed the original series `f`. If you really need to assign to something else then remove `inplace=True`.